# Selenium WebDriver ruby accessing span value

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

What is the best way to to select this element using Selenium WebDriver?

I am trying to access the `<span>` element through the class `mapResultNumber`. This is the actual HTML:

```
<div class="mapResultInner">
<div class="mapResultNumber">
<span>4</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use xpath = `//div[@class='mapResultNumber']/span`

Answer (score 0):

Using a css selector is a more readable way:

```
element = @driver.find_element(:css => "div.mapResultNumber span")
```

- A dot (period) after a tag indicates the class to select.
- A single space after the first selector (i.e. "div.mapResultNumber") indicates the next tag will be found inside the previous
- You could also use `div.mapResultNumber > span` to indicate that the span tag is found directly beneath the div

Comment: Your answer seems to me new, as I have never seen such technique. Can you give me the link where you found it?

Comment: What do you mean this answer seems new? You can view the Selenium WebDriver documentation at http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/SearchContext.html#find_element-instance_method and see the different "how"'s that you can search for an element by. CSS is one of the "how"'s. Please note that SWD explicitly uses CSS3, and so pseudo-selectors like CSS2's (Sizzle library) :contains('foo') do not work.
You can learn more about CSS3 at http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/  or for a tutorial http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200601/css_3_selectors_explained/